# SyliusTaxonomyBundle Override Taxonomy entity and mapping

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to override Taxonomy with my own. Since I don't need Taxon(s), I won't to leave `root` field null and use only Taxonomy `name` field. So, in my own bundle I have a Taxonomy enitity.

```
use Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Model\Taxonomy as BaseTaxonomy;

class Taxonomy extends BaseTaxonomy
{
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Since I don't want to override the my bundle (I'm probably going to override it with SyliusProductBundle in the future), I wanted to override the mapping orm.xml file in the app/Resources directory.

This is where the problem is. I can't override it so that, when I create the tables with `doctrine:schema:update --force`, doctrine sees my mapping file and skips SyliusTaxonomyBundle file. I've tried many solutions. This is the lates...

```
app
    Resources
        SyliusTaxonomyBundle
            Resources
                config
                    doctrine
                        model
                            Taxonomy.orm.xml
```

I've read the section in the Symfony2 [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc) but I can't get it to work

Comment: Check this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html, it states `Due to the way Doctrine works, it is not possible to override entity mapping of a bundle`. Can you post your `Taxonomy.orm.xml` mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in me. Just put the file `Taxonomy.orm.xml` in your bundles doctrine directory and all will be good. This is just a stupid mistake of mine.